# AngularJS and SELECT: how to programmatically set the initial item?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I have such a code: (JADE syntax)

```
    select(ng-model="eventTypeUI")
           option(ng-repeat="c in eventUI", ng-value='c.value',
               ng-disabled='selectEventCanNotBeUsed(c.value)') {{c.name}}
```

I do not use ng-options in select since I need to dynamically enable/disable individual listings with ng-disabled call.

EventUI has the following structure:

```
  [ { "name": "Creation date", "value": 1 }, { "name": "Scratch Date", "value": 2 }, 
  { "name": "Shippment Date", "value": 3 } ]
```

However when I set initially event.eventTypeUI to some number in controller init, I do not get it selected programmatically. Instead, "undefined" blank state of select appears. How I can make it so that by default item with value=5 is selected?

If possible, too, I would like ng-model not to take c.value, but to take object c as a whole. When I tried to assign ng-value=c, I got "[object Object]" in eventTypeUI.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select):

> **Note:** `ngOptions` provides an iterator facility for the `<option>` element which should be used instead of `ngRepeat` **when you want the select model to be bound to a non-string value**. This is because an option element can only be bound to string values at present.

So, using `<option ng-repeat>` can only produce string values.

As for the initial value, make sure it is a string too - not a number like it is now - so that comparison with `===` can work.